Mockk Objects with Unexpected Behavior
I'm trying to do TDD with mockk. I've tried specifying that the mock should be relaxed, so a mocked object's code is not triggered, but the internal code still seems to be triggered.  Is there another setting I can try?

Nevermind.... I forgot I had to 'mockkStatic' for a top level function.  Some of the syntactic sugar kotlin provides can be a testing headache.

Hello, I see you found the solution yourself (great). However, could you please elaborate on the question with a practical example, and then answer it yourself to help other people in the future using your knowledge. See: Can I answer my own question?
